# How to remove or shorten F1 Boot Prompt on NanoBSD 4G USB disk that fail with "fdisk: /boot/mbr: Device not configured"?

Tags: freebsd, boot-loader, pfsense

I have read the [pfSense documentation Remove F1 Boot Prompt](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Remove_F1_Boot_Prompt), however that doesn't seem to apply to our pfSense-2.1.1-PRERELEASE-4g-amd64-nanobsd_vga-20140131-1030.img installation.

The `fdisk -B da0` command fails after `Do you want to change the boot code? [n] y` with `fdisk: /boot/mbr: Device not configured`.

The console outputs:

```
GEOM_PART: integrity check failed (da0, MBR)
GEOM: da0s1: geometry does not match label (16h,63s != 255h,63s).
GEOM: da0s2: geometry does not match label (16h,63s != 255h,63s).
```

A workaround might be to shorten the "The boot0 Boot Manager" timeout value using

- `boot0cfg -t 1`
- `boot0cfg -t 1 da0`
- or `boot0cfg -t 1/dev/da0`

results in: `/usr/sbin/boot0cfg: Device not configured.` and after a reboot these commands result in `/usr/sbin/boot0cfg: Input/output error.`.

How to remove or shorten F1 Boot Prompt on Amd64 NanoBSD 4G USB disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can't do this in NanoBSD.  From the document you linked to:

**Do not attempt this on NanoBSD, it relies on the boot manager for required functionality.**

That in mind, I am not surprised that removing the boot manager doesn't work and/or hozes things.

Answer (score 1):

On my specific pfSense installation (pfSense-2.1.5-RELEASE-4g-amd64-nanobsd-vga) the command

```
boot0cfg -t 30 ad0
```

worked, and then the boot prompt delay was reduced to a bit less than 2 seconds.

Maybe that in your installation `da0` is the not the right disk?

Also, I reduced the pfSense boot menu delay by adding the following line to the `/boot/loader.conf` file

```
autoboot_delay="2"
```

The `/boot/loader.conf` file was empty before adding this line, but the default value seem to be in the file  `/boot/defaults/loader.conf`.

My pfSense is installed in a VirtualBox PC (I'm testing it...)

Comment: @drs thanks for the formatting fix. May I ask where the use of the ` character is documented/defined? (sadly, there is no such key on italian keybords... at least I can copy/paste it :-) )

Comment: There's a brief list of formatting markdowns on the right side-bar when asking a question. Detailed documentation can be found here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help